# Breaking 1 method to create 2

Tags: c#, average, user-defined-functions

Breaking 1 method to create 2

Is there any way to split this chunk of code into 2 method?
one method should be named  GetInput() and the other one is CalculateAve()

```
static void GetInput()
        {
            //declare a counter variable
            int count = 0;
            string inValue = "";
            int sum = 0, intValue;

            while (inValue != "DONE")
            {
                if (int.TryParse(inValue, out intValue) == false)
                {
                    count--;
                    Console.WriteLine("type DONE to STOP entering scores:");
                }

                sum = sum + intValue;

                Console.Write("Enter DONE to exit:  ");
                inValue = Console.ReadLine();
                count++;    // increase the counter to keep track of the number of inputs
            }

            int average = (int)sum / count;    //calculate the average

         
            Console.WriteLine("                      Grade Result");
            Console.WriteLine("Average: {0}", average);    //print the average
        
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
       

        //Getting Input value and Calculate the Average
       GetInput();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void GetInput()
{
    List<int> values = new List<int>();
    int intValue;

    while (true)
    {
        var test = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(test, out intValue))
        {
           
        }
        else if(test.ToUpper()=="DONE")
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("type DONE to STOP entering scores:");
        }
    }

    double average = GetAverage(values);

    Console.WriteLine("                      Grade Result");
    Console.WriteLine("Average: {0}", average);    //print the average
}

static double GetAverage(List<int> values)
{
    return (double)values.Sum() / (double)values.Count();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Getting Input value and Calculate the Average
    GetInput();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very homework-y question, so I don't know if the level of the answer fits.
But you shouldn't really calculate the average of anything yourself, since C# has functions built in for that.

I'd do something like this:

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetScoresFromConsole()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input.ToUpper() == "DONE")
            break;
        if (int.TryParse(input, out var i))
            yield return i;
        else
            Console.WriteLine("type DONE to STOP entering scores:");
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var scores = GetScoresFromConsole();
    Console.WriteLine($"Average: {scores.Average()}");
}
```